# Where can I find the path of my excel file in colab?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I upload a excel file in the homepage of colab
[image]

However, when I want to read this file in my code, it always shows " No such file or directory" no matter I change the path of file

```
df = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/My Drive/thesis_bio/0419_combined_biodyes.xlsx', header=0)
```

How to find the correct path of my file, I check most directory, but havent found yet...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just connect to google drive from colab if you have not and go to that location where file is present and hover on to that file. You will see 3 dots next to the file, just click on it and you will see an option "copy path", click it and it will be copied to your clipboard.